# Promises and switchMap

Tags: promise, rxjs

What is wrong with the following code:

```js
private async getData$(){
  const value = await anObservable$.pipe(
     switchMap(res => fetchData$(res)) // it works
   ).toPromise();
  console.log(value); // doesn't get here 
}
```

`fetchData$` works, but the thread doesn't reach the `console.log`.
No error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting promise will only resolve once `anObservable$` completes. If it runs forever, the promise never resolves. If you're only interested in one emission from `anObservable$`, you can do:

```js
private async getData$(){
  const value = await anObservable$.pipe(
     switchMap(res => fetchData$(res)),
     take(1)
   ).toPromise();
  console.log(value);
}
```

You probably want something like this anyway because the promise will resolve with the last emission of its observable once the observable completes. Any emissions prior to that are dropped.

Comment: the `.toPromise()` at the end doesn't force `anObservable$` to complete?

Comment: It does not. Not sure what that would look like, come to think of it. If you want to force `anObservable$` to complete, you'd use an operator for that; e.g. `take`, `takeUntil`, etc.